# Git Clone Vs Git Create Repository

Tags: git, github, clone, git-clone, review-board

What is the **difference** between ,

**1.** Select **Git Clone ?**

**2.** Select **Git Create repository here ..**   and then **Pull** from repository ?

As shown like image.

[image: Git Repo create]

**EDIT :**

Actually we are going to use **Review Board** as our **code review tool**.That tool requires to create **GIT Clone** (1) method for create GIT.But currently we are using 2 option as for our developments.So because of that there must be fundamentally (behind the seen) differences of those 2 methods.**What is that ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git Clone just clones an existing repo (that other people already work) from a specified URL. On the other hand to create a new repo means start a new repo from the beginning.

Comment: out of the 3 answers here, this is the only one that gets it

Comment: Do you have any idea about why clone is suitable for Review board ?

Comment: Review Board supports multiple source code repositories. Works best if you have a primary Git server where people clone from and push their changes to. Once you have a local clone, you can start setting up your repository in Review Board.

Comment: Thanks for clean explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in Windows context:

1. Is copy an Folder with content
2. Is create a Folter and later copy the content

Comment: I need a explanation as Git Context.The real difference of 2 methods or no difference at all.

Comment: 1 is less steps to make than 2, else there should be no differences. I would prefer 1 over 2 in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Hardly any difference at all: the files in the repository will be the same and the history will be the same.  It's possible that the repository configuration will wind up slightly different -- I think that clone sets some default branch mappings, while just pulling might not establish those links by default.